# Hands-on definition of cotorsion quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, torsion-groups

Let $M$ be an $R$-module for some ring $R$. We usually define the torsion submodule $\mathrm TM\subseteq M$ as $\mathrm TM=\{m\in M\colon \exists r\in R, r\nmid 0\colon rm=0 \}$.  We call $M$ torsion if $\mathrm TM=M$.

This is quite different from the definition of a cotorsion module: $M$ is cotorsion if $\operatorname{Ext}^i(F,M)=0$ for all torsion-free modules $F$.

*My questions*

1. does every module have a cotorsion quotient?
2. what does not look like, i.e., what is the respective kernel?
3. is there a homological definition of a torsion module? Something like $M$ is torsion if $\operatorname{Tor}_1(M, F)$ for every torsion-free (free?) module $F$.

*Own thoughts*

To adress the first question, one could do the following:

$$\mathrm TM=\varinjlim_{\text{torsion modules $T\subseteq M$}}T\subseteq M.$$

It is a submodule of $M$ by exactness of $\varinjlim$, and it is torsion because any element of $\mathrm TM$ has as representative a torsion element.

Now, we already know what a cotorsion module is.  What is

$$M\to\varprojlim_{\text{cotorsion modules $M\twoheadrightarrow C$}}   =:\mathrm CM?$$

Is this even a quotient of $M$? Is it cotorsion? If not, does {cotorsion quotient modules of $M$} even have a unique minimal element?